# Can't determine a good way to handle caching data from an external site in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rails-activerecord

So the core data of my application (rails) depends on data from an external site.  But I am a little lost at how I should handle not repeatably querying the external site for the data **and** if I should be translating the data into locally persisted objects. I know both Rails and ActiveRecord provide ways of caching.

Basically, I am retrieving Classroom course information in the form of an array of hashes, each hash representing a course object.  In addition, each course object retains a URI to retrieve that specific course info from the external REST service.

I am currently considering something like:

- mapping the external data to an object that is persisted to my local database
- utilizing caching with Rails and setting an expiration date.
- Updating (uncertain): When retrieving a record from Rails cache, if expired, somehow set it up to retrieve that course from the external source using the URI provided by the external site.  Maybe this is service?

Any suggestions on the above?

Answer (score 0):

With the first option--mapping the external data into your own model which is persisted to your DB--that's fine as long as you have a sane way of syncing the data.

I've used [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) with some workers to continually poll for changes and update my local records. It's better if the external service provides some way of telling when its data has changed (such as publishing to a service like [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/), or providing some feed with metadata about other feeds) rather than forcing clients to pull data and check for changes. 
Either way, you'll still need to update what has changed, and managing this with a background worker is probably the way to go.

Comment: With the background worker process as you suggested would that be like using something like cron  to poke the site to kick off the process for making updates when needed?

Comment: Sidekiq has built-in scheduling, so you could have a worker that you start that reschedules itself to go again in 5 minutes or whatever interval you want using `perform_at(5.minutes.from_now)`. A sidekiq worker is just a class that includes `Sidekiq::Worker` and implements a `perform` method that does whatever you want. It integrates really easily with Rails. Check out the docs: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: So, no need for cron or anything outside of Rails.